# subsequent rows in table have darker translucent border-top

Tags: html, css, border, html-table, alpha

It appears that the top border of any non-first row in a `table` element is colored differently if that color is translucent (that is, with an alpha of `0 < α < 1`).

The first row looks fine, but the second through *n*th rows look darker. This only happens if the color is translucent. My suspicion is that there's some overlapping of translucent borders going on here, but I can't figure out what, since the borders are only on top.

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/chharvey/pen/qdNZdK?editors=110

Here's what it looks like compared to a `div` with `p`s as rows, and `span`s as cells. (`table` on the left, `div` on the right.)

[image: a comparison of a table and a table-like structure using divs and ps. each has 3 rows and each row has 3 columns. each row has a border-top of a translucent color. the borders on the 2nd and 3rd rows of the table appear darker than they should be.]

If I add the following css, the div now appears exactly the same as the table, with the buggy borders:

```
div {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
p {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: actually it looks like a browser rendering issue rather than a css. IE is ok, chrome Not and not Sure about FF. It maybe a webkit browser issue. have a look here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591499/chrome-bug-with-colspan-and-border

Comment: from the link above this is the fix --- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVLeyp

Comment: thanks @TasosAnastasiou. If you could post an answer explaining why `border-collapse: separate;` seems to fix the bug, that would be wonderful.

Comment: I didn't know about the bug, but i suspected it was a chrome bug as it works ok in IE. and then i searched and saw @misterManSam answer from the link in my 1st comment. give him a point :))