# Google Chrome - GridView cell border is not properly displayed

Tags: google-chrome, gridview, asp-classic, border

I need to set borders around one specific cell in the GridView. It is done using following code:

```
gvTrips.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Dashed;
gvTrips.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].BorderWidth = 4;
gvTrips.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].BorderColor = Color.DarkBlue;
gvTrips.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Font.Size = FontUnit.Larger;
gvTrips.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Font.Bold = true;
```

Everything looks ok in
[IE (v 11.0.9600.1823) and Firefox (v 38.0.1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCotZ.png).

But Google Chrome (v 49.0.2623.112) displayes it like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgL6q.png).

Does anybody know how to fix cell borders in Google Chrome? Or maybe some better way how to set borders around one specific cell in the GridView.

Comment: Try just using css.  Apply a class to that specific cell either in RowDataBound or PreRenderComplete

Comment: I tried to assign CssClass: gvTrips.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].CssClass = "selectedCell"; where .selectedCell{
    border-style:dashed;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:darkblue;
    font-size:larger;
    font-weight:bold;
}, but the result was the same. Also adding the style like gvTrips.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Style.Add("border-style", "dashed"); didn't help. I think style of the cell is set properly. The problem seems to be with the colspan property in the previous and next row.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me and my searching skills.

Answer can be found here: [Chrome bug with colspan and border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591499/chrome-bug-with-colspan-and-border)