# Chrome render bug with border-collapse

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Chrome renders this markup incorrectly [(see jsfiddle for full markup)](https://jsfiddle.net/31p7osd8/).

```
table { border-collapse: collapse }
```

Here it is in Chrome:

[image]

and the identical markup in Firefox or Edge:

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Chrome bug with colspan and border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591499/chrome-bug-with-colspan-and-border), this is a Chrome [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356132) since 2008... which is not fixed yet.

One workaround for this issue is: not use `colspan`. Sample code is:

```
<tr>
  <td class=A>1</td>
  <td class=A>2</td>
  <td class=A>3</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

instead of

```
  <tr>
    <td class=A>1</td>
    <td class=A>2</td>
    <td class=A>3</td>
    <td colspan=3></td>
  </tr>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/tau7gmhf/2/) for your example.

Or, you can use [mistermansam's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25591740/707451) by abandon `border-collapse`.

Comment: My solution in this case was to turn off the borders and only use background-colors in the cells.